# What is this series? Dragons disguised as humans

Tags: story-identification

The main character is a detective and is a human and dragon. 
There is a secret war between mankind and dragons that can take human form.

I read the book in the 90s. there's magic and the setting is a major city. It was an English young adult type book, fantasy adventure genre. I remember it being dark.

Comment: Could you tell us how along ago you read this, or any other details? Things like, age group (that is, children or adult stories), and the language you read it in? :)

Comment: I remember one story in the _Dragonlance_ series that had dragons go undercover as humans, to find out things. But that didn't involve a detective or a war.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  I read the book in the 90s.  there's magic and the setting is a major city.  Anonymous Rex sounds interesting and strikingly on point but is not the book I'm trying to remember.  This site is awesome!  It was an English young adult type book, fantasy adventure genre.  I remember it being dark.

Comment: Same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92183/what-is-this-series-dragons-disguised-as-humans/ maybe?

Answer (score 5):

Are you perhaps thinking of Eric Garcia's *[Anonymous Rex](http://www.januarymagazine.com/crfiction/trex.html)*?

It involves dinosaurs (not dragons) that dress as humans, but the main character is a private detective.

Comment: There was a terrible TV movie of this, starring one of the Baldwin brothers.

Answer (score 1):

Comic book okay? There’s John Dagon in *The Southern Knights* — though I don’t think he’s described as a detective.